# Two submanifolds intersecting in a point implies the same tangent space

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be $n-$ dimensional differentiable manifold  and $N_1, N_2$ two submanifols of $M$ with the same dimension $k < n$. Supose that $N_1\cap N_2 = \{p\}$. Is it true that $T_pN_1 = T_pN_2?$

**The context:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth bounded open domain
satisfying the interior sphere condition, that is, given $y \in \partial \Omega$, there exists $x \in \Omega $ and $r > 0$ such that $B_r(x) \subset \Omega$ and $y \in \partial B_r(x)$. Call $\eta_1$ the external normal vector of $\partial \Omega$ at $y$ and $\eta_2$ the external normal vector of $\partial B_r(x)$ at $y$. I have to show that $\eta_1 = \eta_2$. In other words, I have to show that the respectives tangent spaces are the same. I would like to take $M = \mathbb{R}^n, N_1 = \partial \Omega$ and $N_2 = \partial B_r(x)$ in my statement.

Any help or reference is very welcome.

Comment: As your original question stands, no. Take $n=2k$ and take two linear subspaces of dimension $k$ intersecting transversely in $\Bbb R^{2k}$.

Comment: P.S. The thing you’re trying to prove should just be basic calculus. Of course, you need to use the hypotheses you have.

Comment: Alternatively, take $n=2$ and $k=1$ and $M=\mathbb R^2$. Then your asking whether two curves that intersect in a point have the same tangent in that point. Also the hypothesis you want to impose is not satisfied in the situation you are describing as "the context". You'll have to understand the "interior sphere condition", for example think about how for a given $y$ you would find $x$ in the case that $\Omega$ is a half space.

Comment: Thank you, Ted and Andreas.  Dear Andreas, do you know any reference where I can see the construction of the interior sphere on a C^2 domain? As you said, I have to understand this, but I didn't find any reference.

Comment: It's a convexity hypothesis on $\partial\Omega$. Start with the inward-pointing normal ray to $\partial\Omega$ and consider $x$ along that ray. I don't personally know any reference.